# How to identify and delete old Ubuntu partitions

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, 20.04

I have a computer with two internal hard disks. Initially, Ubuntu 16.04 was installed. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the other hard disk so I could gradually migrate everything. I have finished the migration and and happy with 20.04 and am ready to delete the partitions used for 16.04. But I am very inexperienced and nervous about doing this, so am asking here for the precise steps to take so that I don't screw up my 20.04 installation.
Here are the current partitions:

```
/dev/sdb - where 16.04 was initially installed
    /dev/sdb1 - EFI System; 537 MB; FAT32
    /dev/sdb2 - Ext4; 991 GB (encrypted)
    /dev/sdb3 - Swap  
/dev/sda - where 20.04 was installed
    /dev/sda1 - EFI System; 537 MB; FAT32
    /dev/sda2 - Ext4; 991 GB (not encrypted)
```

I obviously want to keep /dev/sda2 and want to replace the encrypted /dev/sdb2 with some other partition. I have no idea what to do about the two EFI partitions. I presume, but am not entirely sure, that the Swap partition is being used by both 16.04 and 20.04, so it should be left alone.
So, any help in the precise applications and steps to use to achieve my goal, which is to completely remove 16.04 and boot directly to 20.04, would be very much appreciated.
Additional diagnostic info:

```
    free -h
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           15Gi       2.3Gi       4.1Gi       878Mi       9.1Gi        12Gi
    Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

    swapon -s
    Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
    /swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2

    grep -i swap /etc/fstab
    /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

    df | grep -v loop
    Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    udev             8092712         0   8092712   0% /dev
    tmpfs            1627296      1944   1625352   1% /run
    /dev/sda2      959863856 375460708 535574940  42% /
    tmpfs            8136472    641684   7494788   8% /dev/shm
    tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs            8136472         0   8136472   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/sda1         523248      7944    515304   2% /boot/efi
    tmpfs            1627292        64   1627228   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: `gnome-disks` is a user friendly application.

Comment: Edit your question and show me (when booted to 20.04) `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `df | grep -v loop`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Output of commands added, as requested

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The goal**: remove 16.04 and unneeded partitions.

**Note**: Have good backups before changing anything.

**Note**: Answer based on given data. If incorrect data, then this answer would be incorrect.

**Since:**

- /dev/sda is your current running 20.04 system
- the swap on /dev/sdb3 is not being used by 20.04
- the /swapfile on /dev/sda2 is being used by 20.04
- /dev/sda1 is the EFI partition used by 20.04
- /dev/sdb1 - /dev/sdb3 were being used by 16.04

**You can:**

Just wipe /dev/sdb by using `gparted` and laying down a fresh GPT partition table on /dev/sdb. Recreate new partitions as desired.

---

**/swapfile**

I'd recommend increasing your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand of what you want to achieve:

**A**- Free the partitions utilized by Ubuntu 16.04

**B**- Boot on a single Ubuntu which is the latest you have installed :

```
/dev/sda - where 20.04 was installed
    /dev/sda1 - EFI System; 537 MB; FAT32
    /dev/sda2 - Ext4; 991 GB (not encrypted)
```

**C**- Use the Swap partition for your latest Ubuntu

I would suggest the following:

1 - Boot on your 20.04 Ubuntu

2 - Open a terminal and check if the Swap partition is used by the system:

```
free -m
```

this should show you what is used in memory, including the swap partition. If it does not appear you will have to add it on `/etc/fstab`. (solves C)

3 - Use `gparted` or `gnome-disks` to delete partitions `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/dsb2`. The use of both tools is fairly intuitive: you click on a partition and remove it. (Solves A and B)

4 - Once you have done that, you have an unused space that you can select to create another partition. I would suggest an `ext4` partition

I hope I answer to your requirements.

Comment: Boot with your live USB, open gparted and edit or delete whichever you want.

Comment: I would keep ESP - efi system partition on both drives. Although normally only one is used, good place to backup the working ESP.

Comment: @oldfred How do I identify which is the working ESP

Comment: UEFI uses GUID/partUUID to find ESP to boot from. To see UEFI GUID: `sudo efibootmgr -v` and then to see partUUID `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` One of the FAT32 partitions' partUUID should match entry in efibootmgr.

Comment: @oldfred OK. Supposing the computer can no longer boot from the UEFI partition. Is it simply a question of copying the files from the backup UEFI partition to the live partition, or is there something else to consider? (Assuming the problem is only with the files in the UEFI partition)

Comment: If UEFI entry has correct GUID/partUUID, you can just copy the /EFI/ folders back into an ESP. Generally you can also just reinstall Windows boot loader with your Windows repair flash drive and total reinstall of grub from Ubuntu live installer to add boot files (and UEFI entry). You can use efibootmgr to update UEFI entries and manually edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg for correct files also.